# Codeigniter(3) form validation always returns FALSE for GET method

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-form-validation

codeigniter form validation is not working properly for `GET` method, it returns always false(even if all the input fields are correct) and not showing error messages. But when i tried with `POST` method, its working fine and showing error message if wrong input fields.

Below is HTML form with 3 input fields and all are mandatory required fields which is i'm checking in validation.

```
            **<form action="" method="get" name="ak-api-log" id="ak-api-log-form" autocomplete="off">**
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="bmd-label-floating">API</label>
                              **<select name="ak_api_type" class="form-control">
                                <option value="all">All</option>
                                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                <option value="editor">Editor</option>
                              </select>**
                            <?php echo form_error('ak_api_type', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="bmd-label-floating">From</label>
                              **<input type="text" name="ak_api_from_date" class="form-control" id="ak-api-from-date"">**
                              <?php echo form_error('ak_api_from_date', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="bmd-label-floating">To</label>
                              **<input type="text" name="ak_api_to_date" class="form-control" id="ak-api-to-date">**
                              <?php echo form_error('ak_api_to_date', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="submit" id="userBtn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                **</form>**
```

Below is my controller code. I've removed codes not necessary for the question.

```
public function api_log(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ak_api_type', 'ak_api_type', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ak_api_from_date', 'ak_api_from_date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ak_api_to_date', 'ak_api_to_date', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->template->view(strtolower(__CLASS__).'/'.__FUNCTION__);
    }else {
        echo 'true';exit;
    }
 }
```

Quick solutions will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, the `form_validation` works on POST by default. There's an example how to pass in an alternative data to be validated [in the manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post). Try to set the query parameters.

Comment: Hi, its working and really helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter form-validation doesn't support `GET` method or any other method except `POST`.

You may want to go for an alternative solution as below.

```
// before creating the form validation rule.

$dataToValidate = $this->input->get();

// or you can set this data manually as below


$dataToValidate = array(
        'username' => 'johndoe',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'passconf' => 'mypassword'
);


// followed by
$this->form_validation->set_data($dataToValidate);
```

You can set custom data easily in Codeigniter as above.

Read reference: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Comment: Hi @anees, if you find the answer useful, please spare a moment to upvote it so it helps other people.